# Why is rect not scaling with svg's height

Tags: html, css

I want to transition rect height with the svg's height why does setting the rect in percent work initially, but doesn't persist on hover?

```css
div{
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
div:hover{
  height: 400px;
}
svg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
rect{
  fill: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg><rect /></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *width* and *height* of the `rect` tag are attributes, but not css properties:

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Look at the rules for using the allowed [attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) and [properties of the css](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html).

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
}

div:hover {
    height: 400px;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

rect {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <svg><rect width="100%" height="100%" /></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have to add the width/height attribute on the `rect` itself:

```css
div{
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  transition: height .25s;
}
div:hover{
  height: 400px;
}
svg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
rect{
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```